# Could someone explain this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```js
        settings.supportsCssTransitions = (function (style) {
            var prefixes = ['Webkit', 'Moz', 'Ms'];
            for (var i = 0, l = prefixes.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (typeof style[prefixes[i] + 'Transition'] !== 'undefined') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })(document.createElement('div').style);
```

Why use the '()' to Bracket  the anonymous funcion? what's the use of (document.createElement('div').style)? Is that every time I execute  settings.supportsCssTransitions, ‘document.createElement('div').style’ will be the default paremeter passed into the anonymous funcion? Could someone explain for me?

Comment: it's an IIFE, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function that tests whether the executing browser supports certain CSS properties.

What this construct:

```
var result = (function(arg) { ...; return smth; })(arg)
```

does is create an anonymous function and execute it immediately with argument `arg`, to then assign its return value to `result`.

The same result could be achieved with a succession of top-level statements, but doing it like this is better formatting because the variables used inside the function are kept inside it.

The `document.createElement('div').style` bit simply creates a dummy HTMLElement and pass its `style` property to the function which then analyzes it.